# How to get both guesses replaced instead of the underscores in my hangman code?

Tags: python

```
dashes = ""   
for i in word_chosen: 
    dashes = dashes+"_ "  

def get_guess():
    guess = ""
    guess = input("Please can you enter a guess for hangman: ")
    return guess

def check_guess(dashes):
    if len(guess)>1:
           print("word")
    else:
         if guess in word_chosen: 
             print("The word contains an ",guess)
                # Yes option
             dashes_tem = " "
             count = 0
              # new variable made 
             for i in word_chosen:
             # loop through the word chosen
                 if i == guess:# check word against guess
                     dashes_tem = dashes_tem + i + " "
                 else:
                     dashes_tem = dashes_tem + dashes[(count*2)] + " "
                 count = count + 1

             return dashes_tem
         else:
              print("The word doesn't contain an",guess)
              # No option - will come back

guess = get_guess()
dashes = check_guess(dashes)
print(dashes)             
guess = get_guess()
dashes = check_guess(dashes)
print(dashes)
```

So I have made my hangman code and am in the middle of coding it when there is two correct guesses however when there is two correct guesses it will just say the word contains 'x' but won't replace the underscore, like it did for the first correct guess.

Comment: What is `dashes` initialized to?

Comment: @Synergist 
 
dashes = ""  
#reset dashes to blank spaces  
for i in word_chosen:  
    dashes = dashes+"_ "  
#loop through letters in the word  
#replace dashes with a dash and space e.g_ _

Comment: @AB1 your comments are incomprehensible. Please read through [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) first.

Comment: @Synergist SORRY! I have shown what dashes means at the start of my code now...

Comment: I suggest reading through some Python tutorials. You're doing way too much work redoing stuff that Python gives you for free. Example 1: `dashes = '';for i in word_chosen: dashes = dashes + '_'` can be rewritten `dashes = '_' * len(word_chosen)`. Also `i` as a loop variable typically means a number, but that's not as important. Example 2: your huge loop for making replacements is basically redefining (less robustly) Python's built-in [replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method for strings.

Comment: Can you provide an example `word_chosen` input and the output of two correct calls to `check_guess`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist any idea why it wont replace my underscores at the moment though? I like solving errors rather than improving and completely changing my code...

Comment: Probably because you're modifying the string while iterating over it, which is a Bad Idea (tm). I do not know why, though, and will not, because I'm not going to read through 15 lines of confusing custom code to see why it's a bad implementation of one line of code, when the obvious solution is to use the built-in method. I don't understand the difference between making that replacement and "solving errors".

Comment: @Synergist So an input of word_chosen im my case would be the word Pie. And the output of two correct calls is:
 Please can you enter a guess for hangman: e

The word contains an  e

 _ _ e 

Please can you enter a guess for hangman: p

The word contains an  p

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The difference would be if I use the built in errors I would be changing all my code and not learning from my mistakes in this case. Also if you dont want to check it thats fine by me dont worry!

Comment: @AB1 Listen to Two-BitAlchemist. It's more important to learn good coding practices and how to use standard libraries than it is to be fixated on your code for a contrived exercise.

Comment: @AB1, StackOverflow is intended to build a reusable database of questions and answers -- "reusable" meaning "useful to more than just the one person who asked a given question". Asking "how do I fix this broken code?" without isolating a very specific problem is unlikely to apply to anyone else, thus makes your question a candidate for downvote/close.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in the Help Center for guidance on making a question that incorporates code clear and helpful to others.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually its useful to three people. Me my friend and family...

Comment: Teaching yourself how to do things wrong -- which is what you're asking us to do; reimplementing `replace()` yourself is **wrong** -- is not useful, even to you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I apologise. What do you mean by even?

Comment: In the sense of "as the person making the request". My apologies if that read as insulting somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting from scratch and using data structures that map to the problem better.

For instance:

- Use a set (which is an unordered data structure with constant-time lookup) or a dictionary (of which a set is a degenerate case) to track letters which have already been guessed. To regenerate the word to be displayed, translate all characters not in the set to underscores. Doing this, the exact same logic will be used with any number of unhidden characters, preventing the situation you have here (where something works correctly only with exactly one unhidden character in place).
- Break your program logic away from your user input, breaking down logic into components as reusable as possible. For instance, if you have a function:

  ```
  hide_unguessed(real_word, guessed_letters)
  ```

  ...then you can do something like this:

  ```
  if hide_unguessed(real_word, guessed_letters) == real_word:
    print "You win!"
  ```

  ...*outside* of that function, rather than putting it inside.
- Prefer to store and manipulate state that directly maps to your problem space (the target word, the letters guessed so far) rather than state which can trivially be derived from that content (the currently unhidden set of letters).

---

Functions you could use as building blocks might look like the following:

```
def check_guess(real_word, guessed_letter):
  return guessed_letter in real_word

def hide_unguessed(real_word, guessed_letters):
  return ''.join([letter if letter in guessed_letters else '_' for letter in real_word])
```

Notice that these are *pure* functions -- if you know what their inputs are, you'll always know what their return value is (they don't depend on something unpredictable like user input), and they don't have any side effects other than their return value. Prefer to use pure functions whenever you can -- these are far easier to reason about and test than other code.

Comment: Not possible to start again got a deadline.Don't Worry.

Comment: Having a deadline is even more reason to do a thing in a way that's easy to reason about -- then you aren't spending time fumbling around with guess-and-test loops (I mean in your development process, rather than in the literal code).